# What is the use of java.text.annotation? I have referred java docs but couldn't able to grasp

Tags: java

What is the use of Annotation class in java.text package. Can you explain it with an example.

Comment: In the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/Annotation.html) an example is mentioned. Where one could an an `Annotation("subject")` to `"an example"`. It has nothing to do with java _annotations_, and I wonder whether it ever used. Maybe for adding notes to a rich styled text document?

Comment: It seems to be intended to be used for any kind of information that is generated "on-the-fly" by some analyzer and invalidated as soon as the text is modified. The example in the JavaDocs is a result from a natural language grammar checker, but it could also be used for something like a hint from static source code analysis, compiler errors/warnings etc.